# MANEJO DE ARRAYS EN PHP CON WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo el siguiente codigo PHP de wordpress que devuelve el array de la foto

```html
<?php
$autores=[];
if (have_posts()):
while (have_posts()): 
        the_post();
        $autores[get_the_author()][]=['titulo'=>get_the_title(), 'fecha'=>get_the_date()];
endwhile;
endif; 
?>
<pre> <?php print_r ($autores); ?> </pre>
<?php
foreach ($autores as $autor->$entrada): ?>
    La entrada <?=$entrada->titulo?> se creo el <?=$entrada->fecha?> <?php
    endforeach;

?>
```

[image]

El problema es que no soy capaz de concatenar bien la frase.
Queria generar 3 frases del estilo "La entrada x se creo el y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que obtienes un error en esta línea

```
foreach($autores as $autor->$entrada):
```

La forma correcta de recorrer un arreglo asociativo es `$clave => $valor` y el ciclo te va a devolver primero la clave "admin" y en valor un arreglo numérico con las entradas, que debes recorrer con otro ciclo:

```
<?php
// Obtener autor y sus entradas
foreach($autores as $autor => $entradas):
    // $entradas en un arreglo y hay que recorrer, no se necesita clave
    foreach($entradas as $entrada):
?>
        La entrada <?=$entrada['titulo']?> se creo el <?=$entrada['fecha']?>
<?php
    endforeach;
endforeach;
?>
```

**Nota:** Como se trata de arreglos asociativos, debes acceder a las propiedades usando notación de corchetes: `$entrada['titulo']`. Solo cuando estás manejando objetos se usa la otra notación: `$entrada->titulo`

Comment: Hola. muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha ayudado mucho. Otra pregunta que me ha surgido por si me pudieses ayudar también. Si quisiera contar el numero de entradas por autor (en este caso solo hay un autor y tiene 3) como podria hacerlo ? Muchas gracias

Comment: @Adrián, dentro del ciclo de autores puedes usar `count($entradas)`

Comment: Genial. Muchas gracias @triby

Answer (score 1):

Haz probado con algo como esto

```
foreach ( $autores as $autor ) {
    foreach ( $autor as $entrada ) {
        echo 'La entrada ' . $entrada['titulo'] . ' se creo el ' . $entrada['fecha'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Recorres el primer array de autores y luego el segundo con las entradas, luego  solo haces echo en pantalla de esos datos.

Almenos que no vayas a utilizar demasiado html lo mejor es mantener todo en sintaxis php, suele ser mas limpio.

Por cierto, si haces un for de un array vacio puede que tu aplicación se rompa, solo por si acaso no esta de mas verificar primero si no esta vacio el array.

```
if ( $autores ) {
    foreach ( $autores as $autor ) {
        if (  $autor ) {
            foreach ( $autor as $entrada ) {
                echo 'La entrada ' . $entrada['titulo'] . ' se creo el ' . $entrada['fecha'] . '<br />';
            }
        }   
    }
}
```